# Set layout below navigationBar in coordinatorLayout android

Tags: android, android-layout

The question is simple: How to set (any) layout bellow navigation bar in a coordinatorLayout?

If I use a frameLayout in a RelativeLayout, the RelativeLayout height fill the whole screen include the navigationBar.

Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/MaterialDrawerTheme.Light.DarkToolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/icons" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

And the problem (after I added a fragment the frameLayout):
[image 1](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/150807/device-2015-08-07-224207_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

And the Android Studio preview screen:
[image 2](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/150807/1047944559N_vtelen_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

(Sorry for the images, currently i haven't got enough repulation to post directly here :( )

Comment: I  have already asked a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806112/coordinatorlayout-children-are-not-fullscreen).

Answer (score 1):

Change `android:fitsSystemWindows` to `false`:

`android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`